Which algorithm should be used to merge free hand drawings like lasso tool - add mode?
I'm trying to make an application that merge user free hand drawings, like lasso tool add mode in photoshop.
I tried to find the algorithms but I failed it (https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/simple-polygon I found this one but free hand drawing can be none simple-polygon.)
Below is how I tried to implement with flutter

get points and check it is clockwise. if it is, make it anti clock wise.

get intersect of two points.

combine paths and get pathmetrics

if computed pathmetrics is more than one, think it as it has hole and separate it (*this is wrong. there can be more than on pathmetric even if there's no hole. for example making infinite(8) shape.)

sort two lines in one

return list with contour and interior


But as you can see, this has a lot of problem. Even I ignore pathmetrics problem, it sometimes give wrong points.
What I want to do is making application like this.

as user selected area in free hand drawing,

user can add over it and make in in one polygon => merge. (list with contour and iterior).
How can I deal this? As there are many painting tools, I thought there would be algorithm related to lasso tool add mode but I couldn't find any.
+) I found this point but I'm more focusing at merge two points list. Algorithm to implement a lasso selection tool?
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:label_up_study/labeling/model/drawing.dart';
import 'package:label_up_study/labeling/model/labeling_drawing.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vector;

const threshold = 1e-10;

class ObjectMerge {
  List<LabelingDrawing> getMergedObject(
      List<LabelingDrawing> labelingDrawings, Drawing drawing) {
    if (labelingDrawings.length == 1) {
      final List<Offset> labelingDrawingPoints = getPoints(labelingDrawings.first);
      final List<Offset> drawingPoints = getPoints(drawing);
      List<Offset> intersectList = [];

      List<Offset> listA = !isClockWise(labelingDrawingPoints) ? labelingDrawingPoints : labelingDrawingPoints.reversed.toList();
      List<Offset> listB = !isClockWise(drawingPoints) ? drawingPoints : drawingPoints.reversed.toList();

      print('--- after clockwise check ---');
      print('listA: $listA');
      print('listB: $listB');

      (listA, listB, intersectList) = getIntersectList(listA, listB);
      final Path pathA = Path()..addPolygon(listA, true);
      final Path pathB = Path()..addPolygon(listB, true);

      if (intersectList.isEmpty) {
        final Path intersectPath =
            Path.combine(PathOperation.intersect, pathA, pathB);
        if (arePointsContainedInPath(intersectPath, listB)) {
          return [labelingDrawings.first];
        } else if (arePointsContainedInPath(intersectPath, listA)) {
          final LabelingDrawing labelingDrawing = labelingDrawings.first;
          return [
            LabelingDrawing(
                id: labelingDrawing.id,
                projectId: labelingDrawing.projectId,
                labelingObjectId: labelingDrawing.labelingObjectId,
                points: drawing.points,
                isClose: labelingDrawing.isClose,
                drawingMode: labelingDrawing.drawingMode)
          ];
        } else {
          final LabelingDrawing labelingDrawing = labelingDrawings.first;
          return [
            labelingDrawings.first,
            LabelingDrawing(
                id: labelingDrawing.id + 1,
                projectId: labelingDrawing.projectId,
                labelingObjectId: labelingDrawing.labelingObjectId,
                points: drawing.points,
                drawingMode: drawing.drawingMode,
                isClose: true)
          ];
        }
      } else {
        final List<PathMetric> pathMetrics =
            Path.combine(PathOperation.union, pathA, pathB).computeMetrics().toList();
        if (pathMetrics.length == 1) {

          print('--- there is no hole ---');

          (listA, listB, intersectList) =
              deleteUnusingPoints(pathA, pathB, listA, listB, intersectList);

          print('--- after deleteUnusingPoints ---');
          print('listA: $listA');
          print('listB: $listB');

          final List<Offset> contourList =
              sortContour(listA, listB, intersectList);
          final LabelingDrawing labelingDrawing = labelingDrawings.first;
          pathMetrics.clear();
          return  [
            LabelingDrawing(
                id: labelingDrawing.id,
                projectId: labelingDrawing.projectId,
                labelingObjectId: labelingDrawing.labelingObjectId,
                points: contourList,
                isClose: labelingDrawing.isClose,
                drawingMode: DrawingMode.freeform)
          ];
        } else {
          print('--- there is a hole ---');
          final List<LabelingDrawing> mergedList = [];
          final LabelingDrawing labelingDrawing = labelingDrawings.first;
          for (PathMetric metric in pathMetrics) {
            if (metric.contourIndex == 0) {
              continue;
            }
            print('--- catching up holes ${metric.contourIndex} ---');
            final double metricLength = metric.length;
            final Path extractPath = metric.extractPath(0, metricLength);
            List<Offset> copylistA =
                listA.where((e) => extractPath.contains(e)).toList();
            List<Offset> copylistB =
                listB.where((e) => extractPath.contains(e)).toList();
            List<Offset> copyIntersect =
                intersectList.where((e) => extractPath.contains(e)).toList();

            final List<Offset> contourList =
                sortContour(copylistA, copylistB, copyIntersect);
            if (contourList.isNotEmpty){
              mergedList.add(
                LabelingDrawing(
                  id: labelingDrawing.id + metric.contourIndex + 1,
                  projectId: labelingDrawing.projectId,
                  labelingObjectId: labelingDrawing.labelingObjectId,
                  points: contourList,
                  isClose: true,
                  drawingMode: DrawingMode.freeform,
                ),
              );
              listA = listA.where((e) => !copylistA.contains(e)).toList();
              listB = listB.where((e) => !copylistB.contains(e)).toList();
              intersectList =
                  intersectList.where((e) => !contourList.contains(e)).toList();
            }
          }
          print('--- base one ---');
          (listA, listB, intersectList) =
              deleteUnusingPoints(pathA, pathB, listA, listB, intersectList);
          mergedList.insert(
              0,
              LabelingDrawing(
                  id: labelingDrawing.id + pathMetrics.length,
                  projectId: labelingDrawing.projectId,
                  labelingObjectId: labelingDrawing.labelingObjectId,
                  points: sortContour(listA, listB, intersectList),
                  isClose: true,
                  drawingMode: DrawingMode.freeform,
              ));
          pathMetrics.clear();
          return mergedList;
        }
      }
    }
    // for (int i=0 ; i<labelingDrawings.length; i++){
    //   print('$i list');
    //   print(labelingDrawings[i].points);
    // }
    return labelingDrawings;
  }

  bool isHole(Offset testPoint, List<Offset> points) {
    if (points.isEmpty) {
      return false;
    }
    return !isPointInPolygon(testPoint, points);
  }

  bool isPointInPolygon(Offset point, List<Offset> polygon) {
    int intersections = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++) {
      Offset a = polygon[i];
      Offset b = polygon[(i + 1) % polygon.length];

      if (rayIntersectsSegment(point, a, b)) {
        intersections++;
      }
    }
    return (intersections % 2) == 1;
  }

  bool rayIntersectsSegment(Offset point, Offset a, Offset b) {
    double px = point.dx;
    double py = point.dy;
    double ax = a.dx;
    double ay = a.dy;
    double bx = b.dx;
    double by = b.dy;

    // Check if point is inside the segment's y-projection
    if ((ay > py && by > py) || (ay < py && by < py) || (ax < px && bx < px)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Check intersection with the ray
    double slope = (by - ay) / (bx - ax);
    double xIntersection = ax + (py - ay) / slope;

    return xIntersection > px;
  }


  bool arePointsContainedInPath(Path path, List<Offset> points) {
    for (Offset point in points) {
      if (!path.contains(point)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  List<Offset> getPoints(Drawing drawing) {
    if (drawing.drawingMode == DrawingMode.square) {
      final Offset firstPoint = drawing.points.first;
      final Offset lastPoint = drawing.points.last;
      return [
        firstPoint,
        Offset(lastPoint.dx, firstPoint.dy),
        lastPoint,
        Offset(firstPoint.dx, lastPoint.dy)
      ];
    }
    return drawing.points;
  }

  List<Offset> sortContour(
      List<Offset> listA, List<Offset> listB, List<Offset> intersectList) {
    bool state = false;
    List<Offset> contour = [];
    if (listA.isEmpty){
      print('listA is empty');
      return listB;
    } if (listB.isEmpty){
      print('listB is empty');
      return listA;
    }

    List<Offset> copyListA = List.from(!isClockWise(listA) ? listA : listA.reversed.toList());
    int frontA = 0;
    List<Offset> copyListB = List.from(!isClockWise(listB) ? listB : listB.reversed.toList());

    int frontB = 0;
    List<Offset> currentQueue = [];
    int frontCurr = -1;

    print('--- in SortContour ---');
    print('copyListA: $copyListA');
    print('copyListB: $copyListB');

    final Offset leftBottom = (copyListA + copyListB).reduce((a, b) {
      if (a.dx < b.dx) {
        return a;
      } else if (a.dx == b.dx) {
        if (a.dy > b.dy) {
          return a;
        } else {
          return b;
        }
      } else {
        return b;
      }
    });

    if (listA.contains(leftBottom)) {
      currentQueue = copyListA;
      frontCurr = copyListA.indexOf(leftBottom);
      state = true;
    } else {
      currentQueue = copyListB;
      frontCurr = copyListB.indexOf(leftBottom);
    }

    while (true) {
      if (currentQueue.isEmpty) {
        if (state && copyListB.isNotEmpty) {
          if (intersectList.length == 1) {
            contour.add(intersectList.first);
          }
          currentQueue = copyListB;
          frontCurr = frontB;
          state = !state;
          continue;
        } else if (!state && copyListA.isNotEmpty) {
          if (intersectList.length == 1) {
            contour.add(intersectList.first);
          }
          currentQueue = copyListA;
          frontCurr = frontA;
          state = !state;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }

      // pop
      frontCurr = frontCurr <= currentQueue.length - 1 ? frontCurr : 0;
      Offset offset = currentQueue[frontCurr];
      contour.add(offset);
      currentQueue.removeAt(frontCurr);
      // rearCurr = frontCurr > 0 ? frontCurr - 1 : currentQueue.length - 1;

      // print('insert offset: $offset');
      // print('');

      if (intersectList.contains(offset)) {
        if (state) {
          frontA = frontCurr;
          // rearA = rearCurr;
          copyListA = List.from(currentQueue);

          frontCurr = copyListB.indexOf(offset);
          // rearCurr = rearB;

          currentQueue = copyListB;
        } else {
          frontB = frontCurr;
          // rearB = rearCurr;
          copyListB = List.from(currentQueue);

          frontCurr = copyListA.indexOf(offset);
          // rearCurr = rearA;

          currentQueue = copyListA;
        }
        currentQueue.removeAt(frontCurr);
        // rearCurr = frontCurr > 0 ? frontCurr - 1 : currentQueue.length - 1;
        state = !state;
      }
    }

    print('contour: ${contour}');

    return contour;
  }

  bool isClockWise(List<Offset> vertexList) {
    Offset A = vertexList.reduce((a, b) {
      if (a.dy < b.dy || (a.dy == b.dy && a.dx < b.dx)) {
        return a;
      } else {
        return b;
      }
    });

    final indexA = vertexList.indexOf(A);
    int indexB = indexA - 1;
    int indexC = indexA + 1;
    if (indexB < 0) {
      indexB = vertexList.length - 1;
    }
    if (indexC > vertexList.length - 1) {
      indexC = 0;
    }

    final Offset B = vertexList[indexB];
    final Offset C = vertexList[indexC];

    final Offset AB = A - B;
    vector.Vector2 vectorAB = vector.Vector2(AB.dx, AB.dy);
    final Offset AC = C - A;
    vector.Vector2 vectorAC = vector.Vector2(AC.dx, AC.dy);

    final cross = vectorAB.cross(vectorAC);
    if (cross > 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (cross < 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      if (A < C) {
        return true;
        // clock-wise
      } else {
        // anti-clockwise
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  (List<Offset>, List<Offset>, List<Offset>) deleteUnusingPoints(
      Path path1,
      Path path2,
      List<Offset> listA,
      List<Offset> listB,
      List<Offset> intersectList) {
    final List<Offset> copyListA = List.from(listA);
    final List<Offset> copyListB = List.from(listB);

    Path intersectPath = Path.combine(PathOperation.intersect, path1, path2);
    Path differencePath = Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, path2, path1);

    final delete = intersectList
        .where((element) => intersectPath.contains(element) && !differencePath.contains(element))
        .toList();


    intersectList.removeWhere((element) => delete.contains(element));
    copyListA.removeWhere((element) => delete.contains(element));
    copyListB.removeWhere((element) => delete.contains(element));

    for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
      if (path2.contains(listA[i]) && !listB.contains(listA[i])) {
        copyListA.removeWhere((element) => element == listA[i]);
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listB.length; i++) {
      if (path1.contains(listB[i]) && !listA.contains(listB[i])) {
        copyListB.removeWhere((element) => element == listB[i]);
      }
    }
    return (copyListA, copyListB, intersectList);
  }


  (List<Offset>, List<Offset>, List<Offset>) getIntersectList(
      List<Offset> listA, List<Offset> listB) {
    final lengthA = listA.length;
    final lengthB = listB.length;
    final List<Offset> listA_1 = List.from(listA);
    final List<Offset> listB_1 = List.from(listB);
    final List<Offset> intersectList = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthA; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < lengthB; j++) {
        Offset? intersect = getIntersection(listA[i],
            listA[((i + 1) % lengthA)], listB[j], listB[((j + 1) % lengthB)]);
        if (intersect != null) {
          insertIntersect(listA_1, listA[i], listA[((i + 1) % lengthA)],
              listB[j], listB[((j + 1) % lengthB)], intersect);
          insertIntersect(listB_1, listB[j], listB[((j + 1) % lengthB)],
              listA[i], listA[((i + 1) % lengthA)], intersect);
          intersectList.add(intersect!);
        }
      }
    }
    return (listA_1, listB_1, intersectList);
  }

  void insertIntersect(List<Offset> list, Offset A, Offset B, Offset C,
      Offset D, Offset insert) {
    final path = Path();
    path.addPolygon(list, true);

    if (list.contains(insert)) {
      return;
    }

    int index1 = list.indexOf(A);
    int index2 = list.indexOf(B);
    int value = index2 - index1;

    if (value.abs() == 1) {
      list.insert(index1 + 1, insert);
    } else if (value.abs() == (list.length - 1)) {
      list.add(insert);
    } else {
      final lowPoint = index1 < index2 ? index1 : index2;
      final highPoint = index1 > index2 ? index1 : index2;
      value = value > 0 ? value : list.length - highPoint + lowPoint;
      final insertIndex = findInsertIndex(list, value, index1, index2, C, D);
      if (insertIndex >= 0) {
        list.insert(insertIndex, insert);
      }
    }
  }

  int findInsertIndex(List<Offset> list, int loopLength, int startIndex,
      int endIndex, Offset C, Offset D) {
    int insertPoint = -1;
    final listLength = list.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < loopLength; i++) {
      if (getIntersection(list[(startIndex + i) % listLength],
              list[(startIndex + 1 + i) % listLength], C, D) !=
          null) {
        insertPoint = (startIndex + i) % listLength;
      }
    }
    return insertPoint + 1;
  }

  Offset? getIntersection(Offset A, Offset B, Offset C, Offset D) {
    final x1 = A.dx;
    final x2 = B.dx;
    final x3 = C.dx;
    final x4 = D.dx;
    final y1 = A.dy;
    final y2 = B.dy;
    final y3 = C.dy;
    final y4 = D.dy;

    final double denominator =
        ((x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1)) - ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1));
    final double numeratorA = ((x4 - x3) * (y3 - y1)) - ((y4 - y3) * (x3 - x1));
    final double numeratorB = ((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1)) - ((y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1));

    final double alpha = numeratorA / denominator;
    final double beta = numeratorB / denominator;

    if (0 <= denominator && denominator < threshold) {
      return null;
    } else if (alpha >= 0 && alpha <= 1 && beta >= 0 && beta <= 1) {
      final x0 = x1 + alpha * (x2 - x1);
      final y0 = y1 + alpha * (y2 - y1);
      // print('x0: ${x0}, y0: ${y0}');
      // print(Offset(x0, y0));
      return Offset(x0, y0);
    } else {
      // print('no intersect');
      return null;
    }
  }
}

